# How to get user(authenticated) information even when user is not logged in?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to show user information publicly from built-in **users** table in Laravel. More specifically, Anyone can see user information(**name**, **email**, **username**) without logged in.
I've used these in **blade** file:

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
{{ Auth::user()->email }}
```

But it only works when user logged in otherwise shows errors.
Even I've used **ELOQUENT** in controller and have passed **$user** object with by **view**.
I'm attaching images so that you can understand my problem. This is my ***PagesController*** file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Post;
use App\User;

class PagesController extends Controller{
    public function getIndex(){
        $posts=Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(4);
        $user=User::all();
        return view('pages.welcome')->withPosts($posts)->withUser($user);
    }
}
```

And this is my ***welcome.blade.php*** file

```
<div class="panel-heading">{{ ucwords($user->name) }}</div>
```

Comment: Please post the actual code here, not pictures of code.

Comment: sorry @JayBlanchard, I'm new in stack overflow. So, couldn't catch the convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auth::user() returns the current authenticated user or null for guest users. So if you call `Auth::user()->name` on a guest user it will display the error `trying to get property of non-object` because its trying to get name from a null object

You can use something like this in your blade:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    User: {{ Auth::user()->name }}
    Email: {{ Auth::user()->email }}
@else
    User: Guest
@endif
```

If you want to display all users, use the following in your blade:

```
@foreach(\App\User::all() as $user)
    User: {{ $user->name }}
    Email: {{ $user->email }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: But sir, I want to show user information in else condition also. Is it possible ?

Comment: Which user's information do you want to show? If the user is logged out, how does the app know which user's name and email you want to display?

Comment: You can retrieve any user but the question is **which** user do you want?

Comment: I want all users.

Comment: Thanks sir. A lot.

Comment: Just don't blame anybody when You have too many users to display ;)

Answer (score 1):

Auth::user takes information of the currently authenticated user. So it will o ly work when the user is logged in.

Comment: But I want to show user information even when the user is not logged in.

Comment: why don't you just use the eloquent model to retrieve the information?  For example, User::find($id) etc?

Comment: Ok, have you tried eager loading the relationship? eg: Post::with('User')::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(4) and in the foreach section of your blade file, access $post->user->name? This would only work if you have defined the relationship in your model.